# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find GatewayFilterFactory with name Hystrix

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I have Spring Cloud Gateway 2021.0.8 with the following configuration:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      forwarded:
        enabled: false
      routes:
        - id: portal
          uri: lb://portal
          predicates:
            - Path=/client-portal/**
          filters:
            - name: Hystrix
              args:
                name: client-mobile-portal
```

But during startup I get error:

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'eurekaAutoServiceRegistration'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find GatewayFilterFactory with name Hystrix
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:181) ~[spring-context-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:356) ~[spring-context-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:155) ~[spring-context-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:123) ~[spring-context-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:937) ~[spring-context-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:586) ~[spring-context-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:64) ~[spring-boot-2.6.15.jar:2.6.15]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:745) ~[spring-boot-2.6.15.jar:2.6.15]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:423) ~[spring-boot-2.6.15.jar:2.6.15]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-2.6.15.jar:2.6.15]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1317) ~[spring-boot-2.6.15.jar:2.6.15]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.6.15.jar:2.6.15]
    at com.atlas.psp.gw.Application.main(Application.java:15) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find GatewayFilterFactory with name Hystrix
    at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator.loadGatewayFilters(RouteDefinitionRouteLocator.java:131) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-server-3.1.8.jar:3.1.8]
    at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator.getFilters(RouteDefinitionRouteLocator.java:178) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-server-3.1.8.jar:3.1.8]
    at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator.convertToRoute(RouteDefinitionRouteLocator.java:118) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-server-3.1.8.jar:3.1.8]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:106) ~[reactor-core-3.4.29.jar:3.4.29]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.tryEmitScalar(FluxFlatMap.java:489) ~[reactor-core-3.4.29.jar:3.4.29]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(FluxFlatMap.java:422) ~[reactor-core-3.4.29.jar:3.4.29]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMergeSequential$MergeSequentialMain.drain(FluxMergeSequential.java:439) ~[reactor-core-3.4.29.jar:3.4.29]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMergeSequential$MergeSequentialMain.innerComplete(FluxMergeSequential.java:335) ~[reactor-core-3.4.29.jar:3.4.29]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMergeSequential$MergeSequentialInner.onSubscribe(FluxMergeSequential.java:559) ~[reactor-core-3.4.29.jar:3.4.29]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:201) ~[reactor-core-3.4.29.jar:3.4.29]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:83) ~[reactor-core-3.4.29.jar:3.4.29]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8642) ~[reactor-core-3.4.29.jar:3.4.29]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMergeSequential$MergeSequentialMain.onNext(FluxMergeSequential.java:237) ~[reactor-core-3.4.29.jar:3.4.29]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.slowPath(FluxIterable.java:335) ~[reactor-core-3.4.29.jar:3.4.29]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.request(FluxIterable.java:294) ~[reactor-core-3.4.29.jar:3.4.29]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMergeSequential$MergeSequentialMain.onSubscribe(FluxMergeSequential.java:198) ~[reactor-core-3.4.29.jar:3.4.29]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:201) ~[reactor-core-3.4.29.jar:3.4.29]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:83) ~[reactor-core-3.4.29.jar:3.4.29]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8642) ~[reactor-core-3.4.29.jar:3.4.29]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMergeSequential$MergeSequentialMain.onNext(FluxMergeSequential.java:237) ~[reactor-core-3.4.29.jar:3.4.29]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.slowPath(FluxIterable.java:335) ~[reactor-core-3.4.29.jar:3.4.29]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.request(FluxIterable.java:294) ~[reactor-core-3.4.29.jar:3.4.29]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMergeSequential$MergeSequentialMain.onSubscribe(FluxMergeSequential.java:198) ~[reactor-core-3.4.29.jar:3.4.29]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:201) ~[reactor-core-3.4.29.jar:3.4.29]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:83) ~[reactor-core-3.4.29.jar:3.4.29]
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalFluxOperator.subscribe(InternalFluxOperator.java:62) ~[reactor-core-3.4.29.jar:3.4.29]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefer.subscribe(FluxDefer.java:54) ~[reactor-core-3.4.29.jar:3.4.29]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8642) ~[reactor-core-3.4.29.jar:3.4.29]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.blockLast(Flux.java:2760) ~[reactor-core-3.4.29.jar:3.4.29]
    at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WeightCalculatorWebFilter.lambda$onApplicationEvent$0(WeightCalculatorWebFilter.java:134) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-server-3.1.8.jar:3.1.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory$DependencyObjectProvider.ifAvailable(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:2046) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WeightCalculatorWebFilter.onApplicationEvent(WeightCalculatorWebFilter.java:134) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-server-3.1.8.jar:3.1.8]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176) ~[spring-context-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169) ~[spring-context-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143) ~[spring-context-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:421) ~[spring-context-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:378) ~[spring-context-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteRefreshListener.reset(RouteRefreshListener.java:73) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-server-3.1.8.jar:3.1.8]
    at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteRefreshListener.onApplicationEvent(RouteRefreshListener.java:54) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-server-3.1.8.jar:3.1.8]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176) ~[spring-context-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169) ~[spring-context-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143) ~[spring-context-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:421) ~[spring-context-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:378) ~[spring-context-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.start(EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.java:85) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-3.1.7.jar:3.1.7]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-context-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
    Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error
        at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:99) ~[reactor-core-3.4.29.jar:3.4.29]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.blockLast(Flux.java:2761) ~[reactor-core-3.4.29.jar:3.4.29]
        ... 31 common frames omitted
```

I added:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix:2.2.10.RELEASE'
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker-reactor-resilience4j'
```

But the issue is still present. Do you know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. visit https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud/docs/2021.0.8/reference/html/
2. spring cloud 2021.0.8 -> spring-cloud-gateway version 3.1.8
3. visit https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/docs/3.1.8/reference/html/#spring-cloud-circuitbreaker-filter-factory
4. Hystrix GatewayFilter Factory isn't supported in spring-cloud-gateway 3.1.8
5. visit https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/docs/2.2.10.RELEASE/reference/html/#hystrix
6. but Hystrix GatewayFilter Factory is supported in spring-cloud-gateway 2.2.10
7. you can use CircuitBreaker instead of Hystrix or change spring cloud version

The following example configures such a fallback:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: portal
          uri: lb://portal
          predicates:
            - Path=/client-portal/**
          filters:
            - name: CircuitBreaker
              args:
                name: client-mobile-portal
                fallbackUri: forward:/clientPortalFallback
```

```java
@RestController
public class FallbackController {

    @GetMapping("/clientPortalFallback")
    public Object fallback() {
        Map<String,Object> result = new HashMap<>();
        result.put("data",null);
        result.put("message","Get request fallback!");
        result.put("code",500);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: I just need to change `- name: Hystrix` to `- name: CircuitBreaker`?

Comment: you can refer to [CircuitBreaker GatewayFilter Factory](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/docs/3.1.8/reference/html/#spring-cloud-circuitbreaker-filter-factory) to learn how to use it

Comment: I checked it but still it's not very clear to me. Can you guide me, please?

Comment: @PeterPenzov I update answer and add a example